# The catalog and system-tables tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, retag-request

We have two tags [catalogs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catalogs) and [system-tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-tables). I do not understand the difference between the two tags -- in part because in PostgreSQL `pg_catalog` *is* the schema for the system tables. But, I don't want to assume it's that way in the spec or the other database. However, if it is my suggestion that we merge the two, and keep `system-tables` with an alias from `catalogs` to `system-tables`

Comment: Catalog means something specific for versions of SQL Server from 2012 onwards.  However, that doesn't mean that the tag is predominantly used to refer to this.